# I want to convert 32*32*3 rgb image to gray scale with 32*32*1 dimension using Python

Tags: python, image, tensorflow

The following is my function to convert RGB to gray scale image.

My input image is `32*32*3` where as the output dimension looks like `32*32`, But i am looking for `32*32*1`.  Do I need to resize or re scale this image.

Any thoughts?

```
def rgb2gray(rgb):
    return np.dot(rgb[...,:3], [0.299, 0.587, 0.114])
```

Comment: Can you explain the difference between `32*32` and `32*32*1`?

Comment: [tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(images, name=None)](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/rgb_to_grayscale)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many beginners have difficulty to understand this. Simply I'll explain you. If you have 20elements. You can convert them into ndarray of dimension [20] or [10,2] or [5,2,2].
So in your case, there are 32*32 = 1024 pixel data as your output. You can reshape them back using Numpy's reshape function. It's pretty simple.

For example,

```
print output.shape
// This prints as (32,32) in your case
output = output.reshape(32,32,1)
```

This solves your problem.

Comment: If it really helps, please mark the answer as the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the conversion to happen in the Tensorflow graph itself you can use this function: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/rgb_to_grayscale

```
tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(input_images)
```

Also, looks like you are answering your own question. What is wrong with

```
def rgb2gray(rgb):
  return np.dot(rgb[...,:3], [0.299, 0.587, 0.114])
```

Good luck!